# Bootstrap hides on second .poppover('show') method execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I need to use popover in such a way:

```
if (response) {
  el.popover('hide');
} else {
  el.popover('show');
}
```

But if user clicks 2 times on button while response if `false`, then popover will hide and appear only if execute el.popover('hide'). Quite strange behavior.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JTdgL/4/), that demonstrates such behavior.

How this issue could be avoided?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to match the sample code in this question. Are they both referring to the same thing?

Comment: @DanielCompton if you have always `response = false` then fiddle reflects bug when executing el.popover('show') everytime button fires 'click' event. In addition to that bug, if you will execute el.popover('hide'), then popover will be shown (there is no such functional in fiddle, but does it matter?)

Comment: You use jquery double click event..https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: @shri Where do you see, that I use 'dblclick' event??

Comment: i gave suggestion only....

Comment: Please simply tell what the exprected behaviour would look like?

Comment: @nozzleman I expect normal behavior as it is. If I execute .poppover('show'), then it actually shows up itself. If it is already shown, then just do nothing. Same thing with .poppover('hide'). If it is hidden, then do nothing, but if not, then hide the poppover. Quite logical.